# MYSQL & C#: How to escape the elements in a SELECT WHERE IN (...) clause?

Tags: mysql

I have procedure with a single string parameter to retrieve records from my table test which has two fields id(int) and Name(varchar).
the query in the procedure is shown below

```
Select * from test where id in (strParam);
```

and value in the parameter will be

```
strParam="1,2";
```

but the result will be wrong because query will be as shown below

```
Select * from test where id in ('1,2');
```

but i need the query to be like shown below

```
Select * from test where id in (1,2);
```

please help me with a solution
the programming language is C#
thanks,
suraj

Comment: Which programming language are you using to construct the `strParam`? PHP?

Comment: @konerak Sorry i missed it.it is in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you construct the SQL correctly in your programming language:

```
Select * from test where id in ('1,2');
```

should come from your **application code**, where it's easier to change `strParam="1,2";` to `strParam="'1','2'"`:

- Split (explode) the string into an array
- escape each element in the array (using the correct MySQL-ESCAPE function)
- Join (implode) the array back into a string,

If you really can't change the application code, maybe some SQL tricks could work. Try:

```
SELECT * FROM test where FIND_IN_SET(ID,strParam) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way:

Explode the value strParam to an array and then build up the string you need in the query:

```
<?php 

$arrayParam = explode(',', $strParam);
$strParamQuery = '(';

foreach ($arrayParam as $Param) {
    if ($strParamQuery != '(') { $strParamQuery = $strParamQuery.','; //Add a comma to all but the first occurence
    $strParamQuery = $strParamQuery.$param;
}

$strParamQuery = $strParamQuery.')';

$query = 'Select * from test where id in '.$strParamQuery.';';
?>
```

Comment: Oh well. Not php. I don't know C# ;)